# SQL Reference Large Equation in Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, performance, subquery

I have a large equation in a select statement that I need to reference in a where statement I think it is eating up my efficiency, I do not want to reference it more than I need to.

```
SELECT 'HeaderDetail' AS rowType, ... , [large CASE/WHEN statement] AS Tracking
...
WHERE NOT(@DNC IN([large CASE/WHEN statement]))
AND [large CASE/WHEN statement] IS NOT NULL
```

I feel like each time I call the statement it would need to recalculate the values and the query already takes a few seconds to run. Is there a way to reference the statement without having it to run the sub query multiple times?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you filter the rows in `outer query` or `CTE`.

```
With CTE as 
(
SELECT 'HeaderDetail' AS rowType, ... , [large CASE/WHEN statement] AS Tracking
...
)
select * from CTE
WHERE NOT(@DNC IN(Tracking))
AND Tracking IS NOT NULL
```

or use `Sub-Select`

```
select * from 
(
SELECT 'HeaderDetail' AS rowType, ... , [large CASE/WHEN statement] AS Tracking
...
) AS A
WHERE NOT(@DNC IN(Tracking))
AND Tracking IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I ended up using the sub query method and it is working, also makes the code easier to read I think.

Answer (score 0):

use a subquery

```
select *
from (
your query with the large case statement goes here
) temp
where theAliasForThatCaseStatment is not null
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I ended up using the sub query method and it is working. If I could accept this answer too I would!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 'HeaderDetail' AS rowType, ... , x.Tracking
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT [large CASE/WHEN statement]) x(Tracking)
WHERE NOT(@DNC IN(x.Tracking)) AND x.Tracking IS NOT NULL
```

As a side note, `CASE` is an expression that returns just a *single* value. So be cautious when using it with `IN` operator.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86489/1)

Comment: Ended up using a subquery. I use the case statement to return data as a CSV string so I should be able to apply IN (I hope). Still working on the rest of the code. Thanks for the reply.